# Convert a dataframe to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe

**I have this dataframe**

```
     Begin    End    Duration  ID
42   40680    40846    167     18
```

**and I want to convert a numpy array in this form :**

```
array([40680 , 40860 ,167,18])
```

I am using for conversion as_matrix function and I used after it
reshape(1,4) but it is not working!! It is getting me this format :
`[[40680 40846   167    18]]` any suggestions please ? I need to convert
it to that format so I can apply 'precision_recall_curve' function.

Comment: Try `array.ravel()` instead of `reshape`. So, if the dataframe is `df` : `df.values.ravel()` or simply : `np.ravel(df)`.

Comment: Sorry but even this solution is not working it get me an array like this : [40680 40846   167    18]

Comment: Isn't that what you were expecting?

Comment: no . I want it to be this way : array([40680 , 40860 ,167,18])

Comment: @jaouaemna, you seems to be confused by the result of `print(array)` command, which per default doesn't show comas - try @ Divakar's solution: `np.ravel(df)` in iPython or in Jupiter

Answer (score 2):

You have something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]}, index=[42])
Out[27]: 
    a  b  c
42  1  2  3
```

You want to get a single row as a NumPy array:

```
df.loc[42].values
Out[30]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: sorry ! but it is not working!   this is what I get !  [40680 40846   167    18]    and I have applied  y_true = eval_seg.loc[42].values!  I am sure that the input format is a dataframe   this is what I get when I print type of (eval_seg)   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @jaouaemna: Sorry but I have no idea what you are saying now.  Maybe if you can add more detail with full executable code to your question....

Comment: well I have as input a dataframe ! and I want to convert it to numpy array as the format that I mentioned before. because I want to use that array as input in a function ''precision_recall_curve'' that calculates the precision and recall between two arrays.   So when I use this array [40680 40846 167 18] the function get me as error : "ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified"

Comment: @jaouaemna: I see.  That's a different question--you need to read the docs at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html and note that it requires "binary" input, not any numbers as you are using.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't pay attention to that! I will see how I can calculate the precision and recall in a different way or may be I could implement the formula directly in python.